# SharedElementTransition in Fragment with Jetpack Nav Framework

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I have two fragments where `Fragment.A` launches `Fragment.B`. In `Fragment.A` i have a `Recycler` which on item click starts `Fragment.B` with an `ImageView` element transition.

```
 findNavController().navigate(
                HomeFragmentDirections.actionAFragmentToBFragment(item.id),
                FragmentNavigatorExtras(
                    thumb to "${item.id}_thumb"
                )
            )
```

this works - i get the transition. Now, how to do it when navigating back from `Fragment.B` to `Fragment.A`. I've tried using

```
sharedElementReturnTransition = TransitionInflater.from(context).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move)
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. In my case i had to `postponeEnterTransition` and resume it once the RecyclerView was done with layout out the layout.